# React - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class TodoCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.userInput = React.createRef();

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      description: "",
      date: new Date(),
      users: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            users: response.data.map((user) => user.username),
            username: response.data[0].username,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        err.status(400).json("Error:" + err.response);
      });
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  onChangeDescription(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  onChangeDate(date) {
    this.setState({
      date: date,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todo = {
      username: this.state.username,
      descriptipn: this.state.description,
      date: this.state.date,
    };

    console.log(todo);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/todos/add", todo)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    // window.location = "/";
  }
```

Path `http://localhost:5000/todos/add` it's correct. Backend post processes works too. I think this problem could be caused by everything, I can't find where I went wrong. I would be grateful if you could help me with this.

[image]

Here is my routing:

```
router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

  const newTodo = new Todo({
    username,
    description,
    date,
  });

  newTodo
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json("Todo added!"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const todoSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Todo = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);

module.exports = Todo;
```

Using insomnia, I can save data to mongodb Atlas and have it processed. I can add the user in the frontend without any problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZhE8.png)

Comment: We'll need more information about the backend service that's returning the 400. What input validation does it have? Have you checked what data is being received by the service?

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info but we still can't see what value is actually received in the request body on the service.

Comment: If i understood your question, you can see the values in the photo I added last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo when defining the request payload. "descriptipn" should be "description", otherwise your service rejects the request because the description field has been made required.

It should be:

```
const todo = {
    username: this.state.username,
    description: this.state.description,
    date: this.state.date,
};
```

Comment: thank you it's work! I've been reviewing the codes for 3 days

Comment: Haha no worries, glad to help. Mark the answer as accepted so future users with a similar problem can find it.